# MVVMLight ViewModelLocator on a UserControl

Tags: xaml, mvvm-light

Is it possible to use the MVVMLight ViewModelLocator on a UserControl.
I have added it to my user control in the same way as is done on the MainWindow, but i get an error/popup in VS2010 stating "Cannot find resource named 'Locator'. Resource names are case sensitive."

Has anyone tried this?

Code i have thus far is pretty much a standard MVVMLight WPF starter application...

**UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="NavTest3.PersonControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="116" MinWidth="250" Width="300"
         DataContext="{Binding Person, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
         >

<!---->
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

App.xaml contains..

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!--Global View Model Locator-->
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                         d:IsDataSource="True" />
</Application.Resources>
```

so the issue is with setting "DataContext="{Binding Person, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" on the userControl."

As mentioned, doing this will mean every instance of this user control will share the same ViewModel, but I want to start with understanding this issue before moving on..

Comment: Posting your code would be helpful.

Comment: can you post your locator code that pertains to this particular section?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, you need to create a static resource in your user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="MvvmLight1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"

             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MvvmLight1.ViewModel"
             >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

but IMO it's not a good idea to use MVVM Light ViewModelLocator for UserControles because it is a static property and when you are going to instantiate multiple instances of your user control there are going to have the same common ViewModel so they all act same and this is not what we want for a UserControl in case you decide to use it once in your entire project.

to get around this problem you need to modify the ViewModelLocator by making all the properties Non static for instance :

```
 public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        //         v--- You got to comment this out
        private /*static*/ MainViewModel _main;

        public ViewModelLocator()
        {            
            CreateMain();
        }

        public /*static*/ MainViewModel MainStatic
        {
            get
            {
                if (_main == null)
                {
                    CreateMain();
                }

                return _main;
            }
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return MainStatic;
            }
        }

        public /*static*/ void ClearMain()
        {
            _main.Cleanup();
            _main = null;
        }

        public /*static*/ void CreateMain()
        {
            if (_main == null)
            {
                _main = new MainViewModel();
            }
        }

        public /*static*/ void Cleanup()
        {
            ClearMain();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried that with the same effect. Although your example shows the dataContext omitted from the UserControl, but then how would the binding work.

Comment: The architecture of an application depends on the problem it going to solve, therefore, without knowing the problem it is a harsh statement you made. Furthermore, IMHO your solution is flawed as the Locator is static, the view models that it returns via its properties - and that's what you bind to - do not have to be static or singletons, and can even depend on the application state. Quite a lot freedom there ... Also the AFAIK a resource name cannot be declared twice and it has to be defined in the app.xaml so that other views can use it as well.

Comment: Sorry !! I forgot to paste the datacontext. but it is just like the same way you use it in MVVM light.

Comment: okay. as you say the architecture is important. since this is sort of a test for working with navigation I may have screwed something up. there is certainly a circular reference/dependency in there somewhere. Ill start from scratch and have a rethink. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a problem with the order in which the resources are loaded ... try assigning the DataContext of an element lower in the hierarchy, e.g. a grid underneath the user control.

```
<UserControl x:Class="NavTest3.PersonControl" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" Height="116" MinWidth="250" Width="300">

    <UserControl.Resources> 
        <ResourceDictionary> 
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" /> 
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
        </ResourceDictionary> 
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Person, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
        <!-- content -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Edit**:

Try using the data binding in the property section of Visual Studio to set the binding and confirm that you see the Locator. Select the element where your DataContext should go, find the DataContext property, and then click into the property value area. Now a dialog should open where you can select the locator. Possibly this solves the problem, or helps you find a soultion. Also rebuild your project prior to binding.

Comment: Hi, i tried this, it throws the same error (Cannot find resource named 'Locator') so i still think it must not be able to see the ViewModelLocator (or not be able to create it)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you dont have an exception thrown in one of your ViewModels. Usually when I get that error the Locator can't be instantiated because there is an exception being thrown by one of the upstream Viewmodel builds. Can you post your Locator constructor?

if you want to trouble shoot this yourself, put a break point on your first CreateVM statement in the VMLocator and see which VM is throwing the exception.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I did as you directed and can confirm that the view models are being created fine. I'm certain that the issue is that the view (UserControl) cant 'see' the view model locator. I just don't know why.

Comment: Where is your viewmodellocator? I use it in usercontrols all the time and it works fine. I also have my views and viewmodels in separate assemblies..so I have another layer of indirection. There is a problem somewhere other than what is being suggested below. The viewmodellocator works out of the box just fine, so long as your dependencies are correct and your VMs are not throwing an error that is keeping the Locator from instantiating.